# Merge rows if they contain a duplicate value in one of many columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, string-aggregation

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dcef6/1/0)

I'd like a query that will merge rows that have if they have the same value in one of 3 columns.

- If one of of the following columns matches the rows should merge.

  - customerid, externalid, customername
- It should retain the date and customerId of the record most recent joindate.
- The externalId, customerName & shiptocode columns should be concatinated if they are not the same
- I don't want to update the table, I just want a query.

Given this table:

| customerid | externalid | customername | shiptocode | joindate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 1234567 | Test Customer | 1 | 2023-01-04 |
| 01 | 123567 | Test Customer | 2 | 2022-12-31 |
| 03 | 1234567 | Test | 10 | 2022-01-05 |
| 04 | ARACODE | ARACODE Customer | 1 | 2022-12-28 |
| 05 | ARACODE2 | ARACODE Customer | 2 | 2023-01-04 |
| 06 | CBE1EX | Normal Customer | 1 | 2023-01-04 |
| 07 | ZOCDOC | NormAL Customer | 1 | 2023-01-01 |

They query should result in this result:

| customerid | externalid | customername | shiptocode | joindate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 03 | 1234567, 123567 | Test Customer, Test | 1, 2, 10 | 2023-01-04 |
| 05 | ARACODE2,ARACODE | ARACODE Customer | 2, 1 | 2023-01-04 |
| 06 | CBE1EX, ZOCDOC | Normal Customer | 1 | 2023-01-04 |

I have this working for one field but I'm not sure how to get it to concat the additional fields. It seems like I'd need to use a Partition by but I don't see a way to concat with that.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT(customerId),
  array_to_string(array_agg(distinct externalId),', ') AS externalId,
  array_to_string(array_agg(distinct customerName),', ') AS customerName, 
  array_to_string(array_agg(distinct shipToCode),', ') AS shipToCode,
  MAX(joinDate)
 FROM customers
 GROUP BY customerId
 ORDER BY MAX(joinDate) DESC;
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.6 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: before insert trigger. [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html)

Comment: I don't want any insert trigger, just a query.

Comment: Sorry, missed the "***one*** of" part.

Comment: It's all good, it's a confusing/complicated one.